# Related Items field is null

Tags: item

I made Event receiver ItemAdded. on this event i ll try to get Related  field its always null. But in the display form is not null. please help -need this field, and then parent item.

```
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        if (properties.ListTitle == "Task")
        {

            try
            {
                SPListItem taskItem = properties.ListItem;
                object relitem = null;
                relitem ==taskItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.RelatedItems]
```

Comment: Are you looking for the **Predecessors** from task list to compare with your object?

Comment: Hardik, i just want to receive the list item (related item) that starts workflow and creats a task

Comment: Try `Related Content` or `WorkflowLink`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be sure, try to get the values from **ItemUpdated** event. Maybe the reason why that the values are not available is because they aren't exist yet.

Comment: Hardik, thanks. When item created by a workflow is that mean ItemUpdated?

Comment: Once item is created by workflow than you can get the item values in your event receiver by ItemUpdated event. Please correct me if the scenario is wrong for you.